# Extract ranges from sequential values

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Task 1:

I have my collection with documents in mongodb  with value from sequential ranges as follow :

```
 {x:1}
 {x:2}
 {x:3}
 {x:5}
 {x:6}
 {x:7}
 {x:8}
 {x:20}
 {x:21}
```

I need to extract a list of sequential ranges in the form(the count is not compulsory , but I need at least the first and last values from the range):

```
 {x:[1,3] , count:3}
 {x:[5,8], count:4}
 {x:[20,21],count:2}
```

or

```
 { min:1 , max:3 , count:3}
 { min:5 , max:8 , count:4}
 { min:20 , max:21 , count:2}
```

Please,  advice suitable solution , collection has ~100M docs , some of the values are in 10 digit ranges others in 15 digit ranges , but they are all sequentially incremental in their range?

Task 2:

Same think like in Task 1 , but taken based on custom sequence step ,
for example if the sequence step is 3:

```
{y:1}
{y:3}
{y:5}
{y:20}
{y:22}
```

need to produce:

```
{y:[1,5] ,count:3}
{y:[20,22]} , count:2}
```

Thanks!

P.S.
I succeeded partially to get some ranges picture by fetch distribution by  number of digits range  , but this seems to be very general:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
   {
     $addFields: {
       range: {
         $strLenCP: {
           $toString: "$x"
         }
       }
     }
   },
   {
     $group: {
       _id: "$range",
       minValue: {
         $min: "$x"
       },
       maxValue: {
         $max: "$x"
       },
       Count: {
         $sum: 1
       }
     }
   },
   {
     $addFields: {
       x: [
         {
           $toString: "$minValue"
         },
         {
           $toString: "$maxValue"
         }
       ]
     }
   },
   {
     $project: {
       range: "$_id",
       "_id": 0,
       x: 1,
       Count: 1
     }
   },
   {
     $sort: {
       range: 1
     }
   }
 ])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8lleTrqQExI)

Comment: I'd be curious to know how `$setWindowFields` with `$derivative` performs.

Comment: forgot to mention the database is using mongod 4.0 sharded cluster in 2x shards , the field is not shard key  , I see $setWindowFields is added in 5.0  , not sure how it works for this kind of task

Comment: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354826/how-to-group-by-order-by-with-logical-sequence) is quite similar with your issue in `PostgreSQL`. I am curious to know how can `MongoDB` deal with this kind of situation too. I can only come up with finding previous document [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sraKxZrH9lV). I gave your question a up vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

if i'm not mistaken for `task2` just change `1` in `$cond`, `$ne` to any sequence step you want

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7AgvPO2IY7Q)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      x: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      temp: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "temp_field": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$temp",
          "initialValue": {
            "prev": -999999,
            "min": -999999,
            "count": 0,
            "ranges": []
          },
          "in": {
            "prev": "$$this.x",
            "count": {
              "$cond": [
                {
                  $gt: [
                    {
                      "$subtract": [
                        "$$this.x",
                        "$$value.prev"
                      ]
                    },
                    1//sequence step
                    
                  ],
                  
                },
                1,
                {
                  "$add": [
                    "$$value.count",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "min": {
              "$cond": [
                {
                  $gt: [
                    {
                      "$subtract": [
                        "$$this.x",
                        "$$value.prev"
                      ]
                    },
                    1//sequence step
                    
                  ],
                  
                },
                "$$this.x",
                "$$value.min"
              ]
            },
            "ranges": {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value.ranges",
                {
                  "$cond": [
                    {
                      $gt: [
                        {
                          "$subtract": [
                            "$$this.x",
                            "$$value.prev"
                          ]
                        },
                        1//sequence step
                        
                      ],
                      
                    },
                    [
                      {
                        max: "$$value.prev",
                        min: "$$value.min",
                        count: "$$value.count"
                      }
                    ],
                    []
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      ranges: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$temp_field.ranges",
          [
            {
              max: "$temp_field.prev",
              min: "$temp_field.min",
              count: "$temp_field.count"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and at the end pop the first element from array

Comment by R2D2 after testing in the real use case I hit the memory limit with allowDiskUse: true:

```
   2022-02-14T09:38:27.575+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes",
    "code" : 146,
    "codeName" : "ExceededMemoryLimit",
```

Increased the memory to 2GB ( max allowed ) with:

```
 db.adminCommand({setParameter:1 ,  internalQueryMaxPushBytes: 2048576000 })
```

But still faced the limit , then decided to split the collection to small ones so finally got my results , thank you once again!

Comment: very promising I will do some test in the actual collection , thanks! Giving you +1 for now ...

Comment: yw, i updated the answer for task 2, and the answer will work for negative numbers

Comment: step=1 wiorking , step>1 seems not working correctly , btw I have the collection with only positive numbers but seems  the temp:$push will limit to 16MB , not sure for the actual collection how this will apply ...

Comment: make sure to change the steps it in both `$cond`, i commented both and it must be same, check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MYrAkA9e6-I)

Comment: step=1 working as expected for < 16MB total array size, just one initial stage  {$sort:{x:1}} need to be added , but step>1 not correct

Comment: sorry seems i misunderstood the second one, can you explain more  for example what is expected output for step 4 on  [1, 3, 5, 20, 23] ?

Comment: For step 4 : we must receive: ranges:[1,5] & [20,23]

Comment: sorry i still don't understand, for step 1 i just subtract the current and the previous value and if it's equal to 1 i assume it as a sequence, some thing like [1.2.3] for step 4 [2,6,10],  but seems in step 3 and 4 it's not the gap only between the current and previous? am i right?

Comment: Step 4 mean  [ 1,3,6,8,11,15,19 ]  range is [1,19] because the distance between the elements <4

Comment: check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3zl-PhOoHlc)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of querying - produces result with format `[ { min: 1 , max: 3 , count: 3 }, ... ]`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 { 
    $sort: { x: 1 } 
 },
 { 
    $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        docs: { $push: "$x" }, 
        firstVal: { $first: "$x" }, 
        lastVal: { $last: "$x" } 
    } 
  },
  { 
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        output: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    result: {
                        $reduce: {
                            input: "$docs",
                            initialValue: { 
                                 prev: { $add: [ "$firstVal", -1 ] }, 
                                 val: { min: "$firstVal", max: 0, count: 0 }, 
                                 vals: [ ] 
                            },
                            in: {
                                 $cond: [
                                     { $eq: [ { $subtract: [ "$$this", "$$value.prev" ] }, 1 ] },
                                     {
                                        prev: "$$this",
                                        val: { 
                                            min : "$$value.val.min", 
                                            max: "$$value.val.max", 
                                            count: { $add: [ "$$value.val.count", 1 ] } 
                                        },
                                        vals: "$$value.vals"
                                     },
                                     {
                                        vals: {
                                            $concatArrays: [
                                                "$$value.vals",
                                                [ { min : "$$value.val.min", max: "$$value.prev", count: "$$value.val.count" } ] 
                                            ]                                
                                         },
                                        val: { min: "$$this", max: "$lastVal", count: 1 },
                                        prev: "$$this"
                                     },
                                 ]
                            }
                        }
                     }
                 },
                 in: {
                     $concatArrays: [ "$$result.vals", [ "$$result.val" ] ]
                 }
            }
        }
    }
  }, 
])
```

Comment: Thanks @prasad_ ! This solution seems abit more optimal , but unfortunately hitting the same push limit in my original collection: "$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 2048576000 bytes" here even the $push amount is smaller size ,Thanks!  Your solution also deserve the bounty since it is small size and abit more optimal  , but finally decided to give it to our colleague 1sina1   since he reacted quickly and has less experience points ... , but thanks again for your effort! +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `$setWindowFields` instead of `$group` all data

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "",
      sortBy: { x: 1 },
      output: {
        c: {
          $push: "$x",
          window: {
            range: [ -3, 0 ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "c": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$c" }, 1 ] },
          "then": 0,
          "else": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "",
      sortBy: { x: 1 },
      output: {
        g: {
          $sum: "$c",
          window: {
            documents: [ "unbounded", "current" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$g",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      max: { "$max": "$x" },
      min: { "$min": "$x" }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y7Ev5UsoD03)

---

In PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  x INT
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 5);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4, 20);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (5, 22);
```

```
SELECT 
  MAX(x) AS max, MIN(x) AS min, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(inc) OVER(ORDER BY x) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN x - LAG(x) OVER(ORDER BY x) < 4 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS inc
    FROM test
  ) q
) q
GROUP BY grp
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4bJeLhcdMA1Wie3dWTSp7T/5)